# Вопрос по pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Вопрос в следующем: я использую атрибут usecols при построении графика на основании csv, задается он у меня следующим образом:

```
usecols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
df = pd.read_csv(fn, usecols=usecols, skipinitialspace=True)
```

Мне очень хотелось сделать выбор столбцов произвольным, и я написал небольшой чекбокс для tk, который бы формировал мне такой же массив данных в виде списка.

Получается следующее:

```
s=list()
if f[0]==1:
    s.append(1)
if f[1]==1:
     s.append(2)
if f[2]==1:
    s.append(3)
if f[3]==1:
     s.append(4)     
if f[4]==1:
    s.append(5)
if f[5]==1:
     s.append(6)
if f[6]==1:
    s.append(7)
if f[7]==1:
     s.append(8)
```

Специально сделал проверку на соответствие типов и эквивалентность того, что получается в результате скрипта выше, и

> usecols = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8]

:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, тем не менее, в коде программы они оказались не взаимозаменяемы. Консоль выдает ошибку

> The elements of 'usecols' must either be all strings or all integers

Есть я преобразую результат в строку, выдает уже другую ошибку

> ValueError: Usecols do not match names

В чем может быть истинная причина, и как с этим можно бороться?

Comment: Вы можете показать вывод след. комманды: `import pprint; pprint(f); print(type(s[0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray(f)
usecols = np.argwhere(a==1).reshape(-1,) + 1
```

пошагово:

```
In [30]: f = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

In [31]: a = np.asarray(f)

In [32]: a
Out[32]: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])

In [33]: np.argwhere(a==1).reshape(-1,)
Out[33]: array([0, 1, 4, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
```

или, следуя логике вашей программы [`if f[0]==1: s.append(1)`] (т.е. со сдвигом на единицу):

```
In [34]: np.argwhere(a==1).reshape(-1,) + 1
Out[34]: array([1, 2, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
```

PS `usecols` должен содержать либо номера столбцов в виде целых чисел (начиная отсчет с нуля) либо имена столбцов в виде строк...

Comment: Спасибо, я в понедельник попробую и отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: Кажется стал понимать, в чем дело. Значения чекбокса попросту не передавались в массив.